# TextFields inside VBox

Tags: javafx

I have a list of records and 2 types of `TextField`s: filled and empty. I am putting these in a `VBox`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < records.size(); i++) {
    if (records.get(i).contains("NEW")) {
        TextField fillField = new TextField();
        vbox.getChildren().add(fillField);
    } else {
        TextField filledField = new TextField();
        filledField.setEditable(false);
        filledField.setText(records.get(i));
        vbox.getChildren().add(filledField);
    }
}
```

After this the user can fill in the free `TextField`s. How can I update them inside the `VBox`?

Then I want to check if any of them are empty(how?), in which case I will fill them with `"true"`.

EDIT: 
So I am doing this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vbox.getChildren().size(); i++) {
     if (((TextField) vbox.getChildren().get(i)).getText()==null) {
         TextField filledField = new TextField("true");
         ((TextField) vbox.getChildren().get(i)).setText("true");
         //System.out.println(((TextField)vbox.getChildren().get(i)).getText()); 
     }
}
```

My problem is that when I am printing in the console, I do see `true` when the field is empty. But in my application, the field remains empty. 
Do I need to update vbox or something, after I update all the fields or?

Comment: Step 1: Get the `TextField`. Step 2: Access the `text` property of the `TextField` to do the check/replacement and apply other modifications, if necessary... It would help potential answerers, if you explain which of those parts you're having problems with...

Comment: @fabian I did that but it still doesn't work and I am not sure why. I updated my question with what I am doing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690240/extracting-text-from-dynamically-created-textfields-inside-various-rows-of-gridp/50692626#comment88422024_50692626

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text of a `TextField` only becomes `null`, if you set the property to this value. This is a bad idea though, since you'd need to check for `null` and the empty string (the latter being the result of adding some chars and deleting them from the `TextField`).

In this case the simplest solution would be not to do this and use `String.isEmpty` for the checks:

```
for (String record : records) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    if (!record.contains("NEW")) {
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setText(record);
    }
    vbox.getChildren().add(textField);
}
```

```
for (Node child : vbox.getChildren()) {
    TextField tf = (TextField) child;
    if (tf.getText().isEmpty()) {
        tf.setText("true");
    }
}
```